# Почему не находит селектор cheerio + axios?

Tags: node.js, парсер, request, axios, cheerio

Суть проблемы, если перейти по ответу запроса то будет страница, на этой странице я нахожу много селекторов //h3[@class="lheight22 margintop5"]/a[@class='marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink']. Но в попытке спарсить хотя бы один, мне пишет, что **селектор не найден**, как с этим бороться?

```
tg.command("start", (ctx) =>{
ctx.reply(`${ctx.chat.username}, привет! Запускаю парс.`)
const parse = async () => {
    const getHTML = async (url) =>{
        const { data } = await axios.get(url)
        return cheerio.load(data)
    }
const $ = await getHTML("https://www.olx.pl/oferty/q-iphone-7/?search%5Bprivate_business%5D=private");
console.log($.html());
$(`//h3[@class="lheight22 margintop5"]/a[@class='marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink']`).each((index, element) => {
    console.log($(element).text());    
});
} 
parse();
```

})

Comment: А разве cheerio (jQuery) поддерживает XPath в качестве селекторов?

Comment: Если я в консоли под вашим адресом запускаю `jQuery(\`h3[class="lheight22 margintop5"] > a[class='marginright5 link linkWithHash detailsLink']\`)`, то есть с обычным CSS-селектором, то элементы находятся. А если с вашим XPath, то выдаётся ошибка.